# How does pyspark repartition work without column name specified?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-sql-repartition

There are two dataframes `df` and `df1`

Then, let's consider 3 cases:

1. `df1` only has the same number of rows as `df`
2. `df1` has the same number of rows as `df` and, the same number of partitions as `df`. Think `df.repartition(k)` and, `df1.repartition(k)` were executed right before
3. `df1` has the same number of rows as `df`, the same number of partitions as `df` and the same distribution of rows as `df`. Think `df1` is brought about by `df1=df.select('col1','col2',..)`

Now,

I do:
`df.repartition(n)` then, lets say it distributes `df` with :

1. Partition 1 - {some rows 1}
2. Partition 2 - {some rows 2}
3. ...
4. partition n - {some rows n}

Then, I do `df1.repartition(n)`.
For all the three configurations of `df1` as mentioned above.

1. Can it be said that each partition of `df1` would have the same number of rows as the partitions of `df` post `df.repartition(n)` have? Meaning, if executor 1 got 3 partitions for `df` with a number of rows r1,r2,r3 then it also got 3 partitions for `df1` with number of rows r1,r2,r3
2. Can it be said that each partition of `df1` got distributed identically as `df`'s partitions were distributed post `df.repartition(n)`? Meaning, the row i from both the dataframes went to the same partition

Comment: I believe the distribution is at random, and it may or may not have the same number of rows across the dataframes. this is from my experiment with a huge data.

Comment: could you please post a replicable instance of that experiment?

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to understand this by looking at the source code.

When you call `df.repartition(someInteger)` in pyspark, [this line](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/fbbcf9434ac070dd4ced4fb9efe32899c6db12a9/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py#L1091) gets executed:

```
return DataFrame(self._jdf.repartition(numPartitions), self.sparkSession)
```

This brings us to the Java `repartition` function, which we van find in [Dataset.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/fbbcf9434ac070dd4ced4fb9efe32899c6db12a9/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L3170-L3172):

```
  def repartition(numPartitions: Int): Dataset[T] = withTypedPlan {
    Repartition(numPartitions, shuffle = true, logicalPlan)
  }
```

So that adds a [Repartition](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/fbbcf9434ac070dd4ced4fb9efe32899c6db12a9/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/plans/logical/basicLogicalOperators.scala#L1438-L1457) operation to our query plan:

```
case class Repartition(numPartitions: Int, shuffle: Boolean, child: LogicalPlan)
  extends RepartitionOperation {
  require(numPartitions > 0, s"Number of partitions ($numPartitions) must be positive.")

  override def partitioning: Partitioning = {
    require(shuffle, "Partitioning can only be used in shuffle.")
    numPartitions match {
      case 1 => SinglePartition
      case _ => RoundRobinPartitioning(numPartitions)
    }
  }
  override protected def withNewChildInternal(newChild: LogicalPlan): Repartition =
    copy(child = newChild)
}
```

In there, we see that in case `numPartitions > 1` the partitioning used is a `RoundRobinPartitioning(numPartitions)`. Let's have a look at this `RoundRobinPartitioning` in action in [ShuffleExchangeExec](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/fbbcf9434ac070dd4ced4fb9efe32899c6db12a9/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/exchange/ShuffleExchangeExec.scala#L256-L409)'s `prepareShuffleDependency` method. There are 2 interesting `val`s in there:

- The partitioner creates a [HashPartitioner](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/fbbcf9434ac070dd4ced4fb9efe32899c6db12a9/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/Partitioner.scala#L104-L130) which uses Java's `.hashcode()` and the modulo operator to determine the partitioning:

```
    val part: Partitioner = newPartitioning match {
      case RoundRobinPartitioning(numPartitions) => new HashPartitioner(numPartitions)
      case HashPartitioning(_, n) =>
         ...
    }
```

- The `rddWithPartitionIds` val adds the following documentation:

```
      // [SPARK-23207] Have to make sure the generated RoundRobinPartitioning is deterministic,
      // otherwise a retry task may output different rows and thus lead to data loss.
      //
      // Currently we following the most straight-forward way that perform a local sort before
      // partitioning.
      //
      // Note that we don't perform local sort if the new partitioning has only 1 partition, under
      // that case all output rows go to the same partition.
```

#### Conclusion

- When we do `df.repartition(someInteger)`, we're using Java's `.hashCode` and a modulo operation to determine the partition in which a record will end up in. This applies the `.hashCode` method on your Java object. This is [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16445094/is-javas-hashcode-deterministic) not necessarily deterministic from Java application to Java application. I did try to find out situations where I would not get always the same results (on a very small scale) and did not find any case where the partitioning was not identical. For this, I used this testing code:

```
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
  ("Alex", 4.0, 3.2, 3.0),
  ("Cathy", 2.0, 4.2, 1.2),
  ("Alice", 1.0, 5.0, 3.5),
  ("Mark", 3.0, 3.5, 0.5),
  ("Jenny", 3.0, 3.5, 0.5),
  ("Bob", 3.0, 3.5, 0.5),
  ("John", 3.0, 3.5, 0.5),
  ("Chloe", 3.0, 3.5, 0.5)
).toDF("Name", "Test A", "Test B", "Test C")
 .repartition(3)

val output = df
  .rdd
  .mapPartitionsWithIndex{
    (index, itr) => itr.toList.map(x => x + "#" + index).iterator
  }.collect()
```

- To make sure this repartitioning operation is deterministic during an operation (so robust against tasks failing), some sorting has been added (which makes your repartitioning a tiny bit slower).

Hope this helps!