# Create an almost unique identifier based on a given array of numbers

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, math

Given an array of numbers, I would like to create a number identifier that represents that combination as unique as possible.

For example:

```
int[] inputNumbers = { 543, 134, 998 };
int identifier = createIdentifier(inputNumbers);
System.out.println( identifier );
```

Output:

```
4532464234
```

-The returned number must be as unique as possible

-Ordering of the elements must influence the result

-The algorithm must return always the same result from the same input array

-The algorithm must be as fast as possible to be used alot in 'for' loops

The purpose of this algorithm, is to create a small value to be stored in a DB, and to be easily comparable. It is nothing critical so it's acceptable that some arrays of numbers return the same value, but that cases must be rare.

Can you suggest a good way to accomplish this?

Comment: Seems you should look up "hash an array of integers".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard ( Java 7 ) implementation of `Arrays.hashCode(int[])` has the required properties.  It is implemented thus:

```
 2938       public static int hashCode(int a[]) {
 2939           if (a == null)
 2940               return 0;
 2941   
 2942           int result = 1;
 2943           for (int element : a)
 2944               result = 31 * result + element;
 2945   
 2946           return result;
 2947       }
```

As you can see, the implementation is fast, and the result depends on the order of the elements as well as the element values.

---

If there is a requirement that the hash values are the same across all Java platforms, I think you can rely on that being satisfied.  The javadoc says that the method will return a value that is that same as you get when calling `List<Integer>.hashcode()` on an equivalent list.  And the formula for that hashcode *is* specified.

Comment: Okay, this implemetation overcomes the concerns stated in my answer, because it returns the same result on every JVM. But the computing of hashes in general is still JVM depended.

Comment: That is exactly what I want to do. I should realize this before. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at `Arrays.hashCode(int[])`, it is doing exactly this.

[documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#hashCode%28int%5B%5D%29)

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the array's hash code.

```
int hash = Arrays.hashCode(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4});
```

See also [the Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#hashCode%28int%5B%5D%29)

Answer (score 1):

I also say you are looking for some kind of hash function.

I don't know how much you will rely on point 3 `The algorithm must return always the same result from the same input array`, but this depends on the JVM implementation.

So depending on your use case you might run into some trouble (The solution then would be to use a extern hash library).

For further information take a look at this SO question: [**Java, Object.hashCode() result constant across all JVMs/Systems?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1516843/1809463)

**EDIT**

I just read you want to store the values in a DB. In that case I would recommend you to use a extern hasing library that is reliable and guaranteed to yield the same value every time it is invoked. Otherwise you would have to re-hash your whole DB every time you start your application, to have it in a consistent state.

**EDIT2**

Since you are using only plain `int`s the hash value should be the same every time. As **@Stephen C** showed in his answer.