# Is Java string hashcode independent of locale?

Tags: java, locale, hashcode

Is Java [String.hashcode()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode%28%29) completely independent of [Locale](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html)? In other words, if someone fiddles with the default `Locale`, are we 100% sure this is not going to impact the hash code?

We know that such fiddling impacts `toUpperCase()` and `toLowerCase()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/785091/consistency-of-hashcode-on-a-java-string

Comment: @Bryan I saw that question, but it does not answer the issue I am raising.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Locale does not affect the hashCode of the String (directly). It is solely based on the chars stored in the String. The hashCode is generated by

```
char[] val;

for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    h = 31*h + val[off++];
}
```

but the problem is how the String is generated. If it is, for example, the result of toUpperCase, which depends on Locale, obviously the resulting String is dependent on Locale and so is the hashCode.

Answer (score 3):

Good question, I ran a quick test and it seems changing the default locale does not (thankfully) change the hashcode ...

```
import java.util.Locale;

public class HashCodeTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String test = "test";
        int hashCode = test.hashCode();

        System.out.println("hashcode [" + hashCode + "] - locale [" + Locale.getDefault() + "]");

        Locale[] availableLocales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
        for(int i=0; i<availableLocales.length; i++) {          
            Locale.setDefault(availableLocales[i]);
            System.out.println("hashcode [" + test.hashCode() + "] - locale [" + Locale.getDefault() + "]");
        }

    }
}
```

Output is

```
hashcode [3556498] - locale [en_IE]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [ja_JP]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [es_PE]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [en]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [ja_JP_JP]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [es_PA]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [sr_BA]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [mk]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [es_GT]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [ar_AE]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [no_NO]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [sq_AL]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [bg]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [ar_IQ]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [ar_YE]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [hu]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [pt_PT]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [el_CY]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [ar_QA]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [mk_MK]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [sv]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [de_CH]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [en_US]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [fi_FI]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [is]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [cs]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [en_MT]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [sl_SI]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [sk_SK]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [it]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [tr_TR]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [zh]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [th]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [ar_SA]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [no]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [en_GB]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [sr_CS]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [lt]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [ro]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [en_NZ]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [no_NO_NY]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [lt_LT]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [es_NI]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [nl]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [ga_IE]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [fr_BE]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [es_ES]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [ar_LB]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [ko]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [fr_CA]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [et_EE]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [ar_KW]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [sr_RS]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [es_US]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [es_MX]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [ar_SD]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [in_ID]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [ru]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [lv]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [es_UY]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [lv_LV]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [iw]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [pt_BR]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [ar_SY]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [hr]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [et]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [es_DO]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [fr_CH]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [hi_IN]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [es_VE]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [ar_BH]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [en_PH]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [ar_TN]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [fi]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [de_AT]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [es]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [nl_NL]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [es_EC]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [zh_TW]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [ar_JO]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [be]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [is_IS]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [es_CO]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [es_CR]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [es_CL]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [ar_EG]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [en_ZA]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [th_TH]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [el_GR]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [it_IT]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [ca]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [hu_HU]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [fr]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [en_IE]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [uk_UA]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [pl_PL]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [fr_LU]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [nl_BE]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [en_IN]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [ca_ES]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [ar_MA]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [es_BO]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [en_AU]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [sr]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [zh_SG]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [pt]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [uk]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [es_SV]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [ru_RU]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [ko_KR]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [vi]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [ar_DZ]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [vi_VN]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [sr_ME]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [sq]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [ar_LY]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [ar]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [zh_CN]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [be_BY]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [zh_HK]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [ja]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [iw_IL]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [bg_BG]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [in]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [mt_MT]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [es_PY]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [sl]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [fr_FR]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [cs_CZ]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [it_CH]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [ro_RO]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [es_PR]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [en_CA]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [de_DE]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [ga]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [de_LU]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [de]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [es_AR]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [sk]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [ms_MY]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [hr_HR]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [en_SG]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [da]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [mt]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [pl]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [ar_OM]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [tr]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [th_TH_TH]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [el]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [ms]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [sv_SE]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [da_DK]
hashcode [3556498] - locale [es_HN]
```

Comment: I tried your code with specials characters (accents, etc...) and the hash code does not change according to the locale too.

Answer (score 2):

The hashcode of a given `String` object does not depend on the locale.  That should be obvious from the javadoc that you linked.

However, any transformation that produces different characters in the string will lead to a different (non-equal) string and a different hashcode.   For instance, translating a bunch of bytes to a String using different default character encoding *can* result in different characters.

---

Summary, changing Locale doesn't directly affect String hashcodes, but it could cause your application to produce different String values, and THAT will affect their hashcodes.

Comment: +1 for explaining that, can you give an example of what you said here 'translating a bunch of bytes to a String using different default character encoding can result in different characters'

Comment: @eon - the primary issue is that if you pick the *wrong* encoding, the translation will either give you the "random weird characters" or it will replace untranslatable bytes with some character (e.g. '?') that indicates an unrecognised character.  The actual behaviour for unrecognised input is "unspecified" if you are using (for instance) a String constructor to convert the bytes.

Answer (score 2):

The equals method on String clearly states that strings are only equal if they represent the same sequence of characters (that is, no conversions are going on here).

While that does not guarantee that hashcode does not use locale information (in general it might), the implementation in the Oracle JVM looks like this:

```
public int hashCode() {
    int h = hash;
        int len = count;
    if (h == 0 && len > 0) {
        int off = offset;
        char val[] = value;

            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                h = 31*h + val[off++];
            }
            hash = h;
        }
        return h;
    }
```

This only uses the characters and no locale information.