# Why does Tomcat stores parameter in a HTTP request

Tags: java, web-applications, tomcat

I was going through the DOS attack reported in Hash function of most of the languages. ( See [Application vulnerability due to Non Random Hash Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669946/application-vulnerability-due-to-non-random-hash-functions) ).

Can you please tell me does Tomcat or any webservers stores parameters in a HTTP request to data structure like HashTable by default ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since

- a `Map<String, String[]>` is the most adapted data structure to store parameters
- `HttpServletRequest` has a `getParameterMap()` method.

Note that this vulnerability has been fixed in recent versions of Tomcat.

Comment: Do the newer version use a TreeMap? That would be the easiest fix.

Comment: Thanks... So Tomcat stores all parameters in HTTP Req. My app uses Tomcat 6. Is there any work around in Tomcat 6 for the above vulnerability?

Comment: Yes. Use a version of Tomcat 6 where this vulnerability has been fixed. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669946/application-vulnerability-due-to-non-random-hash-functions

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt: I don't know if Tomcat uses a TreeMap to fix the issue. The report suggests adding a random part in the keys.

Comment: @JB Nizet: I think that's because hash-based maps are a builtin datatype in some languages, so you can't easily switch to a different implementation when that's part of the API.

Answer (score 0):

Link to the release notes of the work-around:

http://tomcat.10.n6.nabble.com/SECURITY-Apache-Tomcat-and-the-hashtable-collision-DoS-vulnerability-td2405294.html

Strictly speaking this is not a "fix" to the hash collision problem, but a limitation for exploiting it with large POST parameter lists.