# Maximum number of parameter passed in a post

Tags: html, jboss

I get this error:

```
Exception during request processing:
Caused by javax.servlet.ServletException with message:
"Parameter count exceeded allowed maximum: 512"
```

There seems to be a limit on the number of parameter passed in a post.

How could I extend this limit in JBoss?

Comment: The question has been answered before on serverfault: [Is there a maximum size for content of an HTTP POST?](http://serverfault.com/q/151090). Also, this question is not Java related (nor the technology stack you post).

Comment: ok. So why I reach this error? Exception during request processing: 
Caused by javax.servlet.ServletException with message: "Parameter count exceeded allowed maximum: 512". I use Jboss 7 and need to deploy my app even on others... So how can it could be solved? @Luiggi Mendoza in the post you linked there is no answer about this!

Comment: @Giant2: Please include such vital information in your question in the future.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The number of parameters was limited in all web servers to plug the [hashmap collision denial of service attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669946/application-vulnerability-due-to-non-random-hash-functions).

You can raise the limit by adding the following system property to the configuration file (e.g. `standalone.xml`):

```
<property name="org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.MAX_COUNT" value="10000"/>
```

([source](https://community.jboss.org/thread/197650))

Comment: Yes, I've tried to do that before, so I just post the link in a comment to guide OP to the answer.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: I upvoted your comment; but in this case, I really feel you should have posted an answer.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron Digulla I saw that post before. Using Jboss (any version) how can I fix the limit of 512? Tx

Comment: So there is a limit (for security reason) and I agree with it. Really thanks @Aaron Digulla.

Comment: Can I use it in the web.xml? If can, then how?

Answer (score 9):

Just in case : for a plain Tomcat the corresponding solution is to add :

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.MAX_COUNT=10000
```

in `catalina.properties`

Comment: I am using Tomcat 6 and don't have this parameter in catalina.properties. I can still post more than 600 parameters without this error occuring. I added this line to catalina.properties  `org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.MAX_COUNT=100` because I want to simulatie this error. Restarted Tomcat but I can still post more than 600 post parameters. How can I simulatie this error in Tomcat 6?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is right! Mr Aaron Digulla had right answer!
But please attention that: in Jboss 7, please insert the line

`<system-properties>`
        `<property name="org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.MAX_COUNT"value="10000"/>`
`</system-properties>`

 right after the `<extensions>` tag, if not Jboss 7 will through error when parse standalone.xml, let me example:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:1.2">
<extensions>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.configadmin"/>
    ...
</extensions>
<system-properties>
    <property name="org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.MAX_COUNT" value="10000" />
</system-properties>
```

Comment: I dont't have `standalone.xml` but `web.xml`, how can I set MAX_COUNT in my `Grails` project? can you please help me

Answer (score 0):

Another way if you're using WildFly is edit the **`standalone.xml`** file and add **`max-parameters`**:

**`<http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" max-parameters="2690"/>`**

standalone.xml example:

```
...

<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:1.1">
   <buffer-cache name="default"/>
   <server name="default-server">
       <!-- change here-->
       <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" max-parameters="2690"/>
       <!-- change here-->
       <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
           <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
           <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
           <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
       </host>
    </server>

...
```

Comment: I dont't have standalone.xml but web.xml, how can I set MAX_COUNT in my Grails project?

Answer (score 0):

You need to paste the following snippet in your standalone.xml of Jboss server :

```
<server name="default-server">
                <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" max-parameters="5000"/>
                <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" max-parameters="5000"/>
                <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                    <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                    <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
                    <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
                    <http-invoker security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
                </host>
```

Focus on HTTP Listener tag with max-parameter value is what make the difference. The Default value for this field is:-

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.MAX_COUNT=1000
```

This was done as a remedy to the hashmap collision denial of service attack as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669946/application-vulnerability-due-to-non-random-hash-functions)