# Richfaces Ajax empty response after a certain POST content length is reached

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I am using JBoss EAP 6.1 and JSF implementation Mojarra 2.1.19.

After the POST content length reaches around 48000 bytes, then the Richfaces AJAX requests stop working. Empty responses are returned (200 OK) and the invoke application phase does not call my bean method. All JSF phases finish for around 2ms and empty response is returned.

What can be the cause and how can I solve it?

Comment: What version of richfaces?

Comment: RichFaces 4.3.2 Final

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue :) It is the same problem like this - [Maximum number of parameter passed in a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12277231/maximum-number-of-parameter-passed-in-a-post).

The strange thing is that I didn't see any exceptions. Maybe the exception was swallowed.

I made a change to standalone.xml:

`<property name="org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.MAX_COUNT" value="100000"/>`, and it worked.

Of course the max post size has to be changed too, but I did it already:
`<connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http" max-post-size="1048576000"/>`