# What is default value for http parameters MAX_COUNT wildfly?

Tags: jboss, wildfly-8

We have upgraded jboss to wildfly , in older version we were facing some issue like this [Maximum number of parameter passed in a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12277231/maximum-number-of-parameter-passed-in-a-post).

In older version of jboss we got this error message

```
2015-02-10 20:04:34,582 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/sf].[action]] (http--
    127.0.0.1-8080-38) Servlet.service() for servlet action threw exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: More than the 
    maximum number of request parameters (GET plus POST) for a single request ([5,000]) were detected. Any parameters beyond
     this limit have been ignored. To change this limit, set the maxParameterCount attribute on the Connector.
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.addParameter(Parameters.java:199) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.processParameters(Parameters.java:382) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.processParameters(Parameters.java:229) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:2874) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameterNames(Request.java:1333) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameterNames(RequestFacade.java:379) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils.populate(RequestUtils.java:1225) [struts.jar:1.1]
```

Now to verify this issue we wanted to know what is the default value for http parameters MAX_COUNT.

On googling i found this discussion where there is no much information provided, on how it is fixed
http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/undertow-dev/2013-April/000287.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Default value of max parameter count is "**1000**", if you want to modify it

In wildfly we have to use "max-parameters" attribute in http-listener.

```
<http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" max-parameters="10000"/>
```

For documentation please refer [here](http://wildscribe.github.io/Wildfly/8.2.0.Final/subsystem/undertow/server/http-listener/index.html)

In 7.x version you can fix by below change

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.MAX_COUNT=10000
```

For older version of jboss max parameter count discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12277231/maximum-number-of-parameter-passed-in-a-post)