# Why was Map<> in Java designed to require two types; Map<> and HashMap<>?

Tags: java, dictionary, interface, hashmap

My primary language has been C#, though lately I've been doing more Java development. In C#, I can define a Dictionary like this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

...

```
Dictionary<string, string> myDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

However, if I want to create a similar object in Java, I need to do this:

```
import java.utils.Map;
import java.utils.HashMap;
```

...

```
Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Why is Java designed so that `Map<>` is created with a `HashMap<>` and two different imports are required to use it?

Just curious.

## Update

It never even crossed my mind that `Map` could be an interface. It doesn't follow the convention of prefixing the interface name with an `I`. I'm surprised that such a convention isn't used there.

Comment: You could just write `HashMap<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();` and then you only need one import.

Comment: Take a look at [What does it mean to “program to an interface”?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/1393766)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that he knows what's an interface and how it's used :)

Comment: I don't know C#, but from my quick perusal of online docs, it looks like you can do `IDictionary<string, string> myDict = new Dictionary<string, string>()`. Do C# programmers not do this? What if you find out that a [TreeMap is better than a HashMap in some cases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669946/application-vulnerability-due-to-non-random-hash-functions)?

Comment: If you want you can make `Serializable s = new HashMap<String,String>`  the idea is the same you can always refer to an object with its type.

Comment: @yshavit Yes, in C# you would use the `IDictionary` interface just that way.  The statement `using System.Collections.Generic` makes both `IDictionary` and `Dictionary` available, because they are both in that namespace, so only one `using` is needed.  It is similar to the way that `import java.utils.*` does the job for both `Map` and `HashMap`.

Comment: What?!?! It never occurred to me that `Map` is an interface... Why isn't it called `IMap`?

Comment: @quakkels: Because Java wasn't created by Microsoft, so doesn't use MS notation.  So called [Hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) is pretty much only used in the Microsoft ecosystem.

Comment: @quakkels: From a consumer standpoint, classes and interfaces in Java are almost interchangeable; the creators of Java likely thought that meant there was no need to make them be visibly different, while those of .NET likely thought that absent a naming convention they'd be too likely mistaken for each other in the cases where they weren't interchangeable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Map` is an interface, while `HashMap` is a concrete implementation, just like `TreeMap`

BTW You can use only `HashMap` if you like:

`HashMap<k,v> hashmap = new HashMap<k,v>();`

Answer (score 3):

Map is an interface that HashMap implements.
[image]

We can do ,

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

and

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

The advantage to using `Map<String, String>` is that you can change the underlying object to be a different kind of map without breaking your contract with any code that's using it. If you declare it as `HashMap<String, String>`, you have to change your contract if you want to change the underlying implementation.

Answer (score 2):

It wasn't 'designed to require two types', but  it is an interface, and any interface requires an implementing class somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

As others said, Map is an interface that HashMap implements.

Java contains three  **general-purpose** Map implementations: **HashMap**, **TreeMap**, and **LinkedHashMap**

```
Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

will only allow the use of functions defined in the `Map` interface, while

```
HashMap<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

will allow the use of all public functions in HashMap (Map interface methods + hashMap methods).

**update**  from the oracle website:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html

> The Java platform contains three general-purpose Map implementations:
>   HashMap, TreeMap, and LinkedHashMap. Their behavior and performance
>   are precisely analogous to HashSet, TreeSet, and LinkedHashSet, as
>   described in The Set Interface section.

but as mentioned in the comments below, java has actually more Map implementations:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Comment: There are more than three.

Comment: ... and `EnumMap`, and `ConcurrentHashMap`, and `Properties`, and [others](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)...

Comment: @EJP: see this link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html

Comment: @Rami.Q Those are three of the "newbie-oriented" implementations, but there are more implementations. The javadoc for `Map` lists all of the ones that come with the JDK.

Comment: @yshavit, i know, but i wrote what oracle said, i 'll update my answer to include the others

Comment: @Rami.Q The Javadoc for java.util.Map is the normative reference, not the tutorial, but in any case your link doesn't say there are *only* three implementations. You can't seriously be trying to deny that EnumMap, ConcurrentHashMap, WeakHashMap, Properties, etc., are implementations of Map. Can you?

Comment: ... and if you were quoting from an external source you should have cited it properly.

Comment: @EJP: i didn't say, that they are ONLY 3 implementations. the main reason why i mentioned the 3 implementations is just to clearify for the OP, that there are other implementations for map beside hashmap. for that i used the quoting from oracle.