# Hashing Keys in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, hashtable, string-hashing

In java, when I use a String as a key for Hashmap I get a little different result than when I use the string hashcode as a key in the HashMap.

Any insight?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Show some code snippet where you are facing this problem.

Comment: Why are you expecting a different key to produce the same results? It won't.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> when I use the string hashcode as a key in the HashMap.

You *mustn't* use the hash code itself as the key. Hash codes aren't intended to be unique - it's entirely permitted for two non-equal values to have the same hash code. You should use the string *itself* as a key. The map will then compare hash codes first (to narrow down the candidate matches quickly) and then compare with `equals` for *genuine* string equality.

Of course, that's assuming your code really is as your question makes it, e.g.

```
HashMap<String, String> goodMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
goodMap.put("foo", "bar");

HashMap<Integer, String> badMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
badMap.put("foo".hashCode(), "bar");
```

If that's really what your code looks like, just use `HashMap<String, String>` instead.

From the docs for [`Object.hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) (emphasis mine):

> The general contract of hashCode is:
>
> - Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently return the same integer, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the object is modified. This integer need not remain consistent from one execution of an application to another execution of the same application.
> - If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.
> - **It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results.** However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of hash tables.

Answer (score 3):

Of course. Different Strings can have the same hashCode, so if you store two such strings as keys in a map, you'll have two entries (since the strings are different). Whareas if you use their hashCode as the key, you'll have only one entry (since their hashCode is the same).

The hashCode isn't used to tell if two keys are equal. It's only used to assign a bucket to the key. Once the bucket is found, every key contained in the bucket is compared to the new key with equals, and the key is added to the bucket if no equal key can be found.

Comment: Thanks all for the answers. I am trying to avoid storing the key as string as it will consume more memory!

Comment: Don't jump to this conclusion without measuring. Why would it use more memory? The map doesn't make a copy of the key. It just uses a reference to the key.

Comment: I know. But when I have over two million records, then storing theirs string keys is gonna make a big difference! @JB

Comment: @user1785771: They use more memory for a good reason: there's more *imjportant* data than just the 32 bits for a hash code. If you need to store a lot of strings, get a lot of memory. Memory is cheap; mistakes due to incorrect use of a hash map could easily be very expensive.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that, even if two objects are different, doesn't mean that their hashcodes are also different.

Two different objects can share the same hashcode. So, you shouldn't have them as a HashMap key.

Also, because hash codes returned from `Object.hashCode()` method are of type `int`, you can only have `2^32` different values. That's why you will have "collisions" depending on the hashing algorithm, for different objects.

**In short: -**

`!obj.equals(obj1)` doesn't ensures that `obj.hashCode() != obj1.hashCode()`.

Comment: I'd use `!obj.equals(obj1)` in the last line, as that's the important part.

Answer (score 1):

`HashCodes` can be same or different for same String so be careful with that. May be this is why you are getting a different result. 
Here's [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785091/consistency-of-hashcode-on-a-java-string) on it. See Jon Skeet's accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use the hash code as the key only if the hash function is a perfect hash (see *e.g.* [GPERF](http://www.gnu.org/software/gperf)). As long as your key objects don't reside in memory you are correct that you will save memory.