# Long value of a String that does not contain numbers

Tags: java

I have a `String` variable that I want to convert to a `long` variable.

The problem is that the String variable will never contain any numbers, so simply calling `Long.parseLong(myString);` will throw a `NumberFormatException`.

To clarify my intentions:

I have a method that returns a `long` from a `String` in-parameter. I want the method to generate an ID based on the `String` variable, to later be able to group the `long` values.

I might solve this using a RegEx expression, but my question is if there's any straight forward way to get a `long` value of a `String`?

Comment: You need a hashing algorithm.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624192/good-hash-function-for-strings

Comment: I see. You wouldn't happen to sit on one of those, would you? Nothing fancy required :-) @JamesMcLaughlin

Comment: @Marcus `myString.hashCode()`

Comment: Simple as that, I feel stupid now :-) @IsmailBadawi

Comment: Although, `hashCode()` will not return the same long for the same String variable. I.e., if I send in `abc` as a parameter, I will get different `long` values each time. I need them to be the the same. Is that possible? @IsmailBadawi

Comment: It should be the same for all strings that have the same value (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/785091/consistency-of-hashcode-on-a-java-string)).

Comment: You are correct, I made an error while testing. It works. @IsmailBadawi

Comment: `hashCode()` returns `int`, not `long`. Though it is assignable, you'll only get a fraction of the values you could get by writing your own hash algorithm, and you'll get many more collisions (strings that end up with the same value).

Comment: hashCode won't work because of collisisions (different strings can return same hash code)

Comment: I hope that you don't expect to get a unique `long` value for each `String` content, because that's not possible - there are more possible strings than there are `long` values, so there will always be different strings that would have the same hash code - see the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

Comment: @SashaSalauyou Show a way of producing unique longs from arbitrary strings longer than 4 characters. Except by keeping them in a map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you want a `long` value.  The built in `hashCode()` returns an `int`, not a `long`.  If you really do need a `long` then you need to use a hashing method that returns a `long`.  There are a number of possibilities, though I usually suggest the [FNV](http://isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/) hash for non-cryptographic purposes.  It is very easy to code and comes in a wide range of sizes, 64-bit included.

ETA: Code for the FNV hash is on the FNV website that I linked to.  Things to be careful of are 1) unsigned v. signed 64-bit numbers and 2) character encodings.

```
long FNV64Hash(String inString) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    // FNV-64 constants.
    long FNVprime = 1099511628211L;
    
    // Needs workround for unsigned 64-bit: 14695981039346656037.
    long FNVbasis = (146959810393466560L * 100L) + 37L;
    // Alternative: long FNVbasis = -3750763034362895579L;
  
    // Convert string to bytes.
    byte[] bytes = inString.getBytes("UTF-8"); // Specify a character encoding.
    
    long hash = FNVbasis;
    for (byte aByte : bytes) {
        hash ^= aByte;
        hash *= FNVprime;
    }
    return hash;
} // end FNV64Hash()
```

Comment: I did not recognize that, thanks. Could you include an example in your answer, please?

Comment: Minor note: `037L` is actually an octal literal with a value of `31L` decimal.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Thanks for the correction.  I left in the leading zero for clarity.  Corrected.

Comment: In the loop, you need to multiply by `FNVPrime` not `FNVbasis`. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fowler%E2%80%93Noll%E2%80%93Vo_hash_function.

Comment: Well spotted.  I have added the correction.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

if you want a simple and easy way , you can use hashCode() in java , and here is an example

```
import java.io.*;

public class StringHashing{
   public static void main(String args[]){
      String Str = new String("HELLO WORLD !!");
      System.out.println("Hashcode for Str :" + Str.hashCode() );
   }
}
```

or you can implement your own hash function

Comment: Only problem is that `String.hashCode()` returns an **int**, not a **long**. Of course an `int` is assignable to a `long`. But you only get half the values that you should, and you have more collisions (same result for different strings).

Comment: hash code doesn't solve ID problem because of collisions

Comment: @RealSkeptic You don't even get half the possible values. 2^32 = sqrt(2^64), not (2^42/2).

Comment: @SashaSalauyou Collisions are guaranteed for any string longer than 64 bits. There's no way to prevent them, with *any* algorithm that returns a long.

Comment: @hexafraction Right, in my comment to the OP I was more accurate: you get a fraction of the values. But then, what's that 42 doing in your comment? :-)

Comment: Apparently I cannot type, it seems. Should be 2^64

Comment: @hexafraction not exactly right. Collisions are guaranteed for any algorithm only if overall population exceeds 2^64. Naive approach: Map<String, Long> where you put new incremented value when a new key arrives. This is very bad and resource consuming approach, but the only one that guarantees that one string corresponds with single long and vice versa.