# implementing the hashcode of a pojo in an efficient manner in java

Tags: java, hashcode

In an interview it was asked from me to show the implementation of hashcode and equals method in an efficient manner so i have constructed the below pojo but the interviewer said that this is not the correct and the best implementation as it can result in an collision , can you please advise is the below implementation of hashcode is correct or not

```
public class Emp  {

    String name, job;
    int salary;

    public Emp(String n, String j, int s) {
        this.name = n;
        this.job = j;
        this.salary = s;

    }

    public int hashcode() {
        return name.hashCode() + job.hashCode() + salary;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {

        Emp e1 = (Emp) o;
        return this.name.equals(e1.name) && this.job.equals(e1.job) && this.salary == e1.salary;
    }
    }
```

Comment: What happens if one of those values is null? What happens if the object passed into equals() is not an instance of Emp?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/113600/3850595

Comment: @KevinWorkman Thanks yeah i agree i have not thought of those situations , can you please advise how can i handle these situations here itself

Answer (score 2):

You are using:

- Two `String#hashCode` invocations, whose algorithm is debated - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785091/consistency-of-hashcode-on-a-java-string) for an interesting thread
- You're adding the salary (as `int`!!) for the final part
- Finally and most importantly, **use a seed**: multiply each field by a prime and sum the results

You can look at how your IDE auto-generates the hashcode to get a better idea.

In Eclipse:

- Right-click on source (or `alt`-`shift`-`S`)
- `Source`
- `Generate 'hashCode()' and 'equals()'...`

Answer (score 1):

Just adding up the `hashCode` is not a really good idea. There are libraries out there (e.g. [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/)) which do this for you. Or you can simply request your IDE to generate one or you. For e.g. [Eclipse has an option](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/09/04/the-3-things-you-should-know-about-hashcode/) of generating the `hashCode` based on the fields in your class.

To extrapolate a bit; let's assume you have the following `hashCode`s:

```
name.hashCode() = 200
job.hashCode()  = 400
salary          = 1000000
```

But you might have another unique employee which ends up having the following `hashCode`s:

```
name.hashCode() = 400
job.hashCode()  = 200
salary          = 1000000
```

As you can see, even though we have two different employees here, we end up with the same `hashCode` for both. A desirable property of `hashCode` is to ensure that the entities which you are hashing end up getting distributed as uniformly as possible.

If you look at all the "good" `hashCode` implementations you will notice multiplication with prime numbers. This ensures that even though the sum of all individual hashCode ends up the same, you still have an overall `hashCode` which is different. You can try it out with the above example.

Comment: Remember, this was an interview question, so the interviewer would be looking for a simple solution, directly coded. Not sure use of external library is what was required.

Comment: @AndrewFielden: I realized that later and have added in few more details.