# What are variables "offset" & "hash" in String.hashCode()?

Tags: java

I've read that this is the source code for String.hashCode()

```
   public int hashCode() {
   int h = hash;
   if (h == 0) {
       int off = offset;
       char val[] = value;
       int len = count;

       for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
           h = 31*h + val[off++];
       }
       hash = h;
   }
   return h;
   }
```

My question is, what are "offset" & "hash"? I can tell that "value" is the actual String and "length" is its length, but I don't understand what the other two are.

Comment: You could take a look at the *rest* of the `String` source code for context.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks, had checked 8 and 7

Comment: Read the comments in the source code next to [`offset`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#116) and [`hash`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#122).

Comment: /** The offset is the first index of the storage that is used. */
private final int offset;

What is storage referring to?

Comment: Based on experimentation, it appears that if I replace val[off++] with val[i] my method works the same, so I think it was being used as an index.

Comment: @KartikChughヅ Read 2 lines above the `offset` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The offset is the first index of the value[] array of chars of the String.
The hash variable is a field for caching the hashCode so as to be more efficient (the hashCode() method only computes the hash if it's current value is 0; else it returns the cached hash)